How to find np.where(A==0) and np.where(A!=0) with a single call
I have the following code:
zero_indices = np.where(A==0) 
nonzero_indices = np.where(A!=0)

But I want to find zero_indices and nonzero_indices with just a single call of np.where.
One way I found to do this is:
zero_indices = np.where(array == 0)
non_zero_indices = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(array.size), zero_indices)

However, when testing on large arrays, I found that this is actually 10x slower than just calling np.where twice.
Is there a more efficient way to do this?

inputs and expected outputs?

.where is already very efficient. You can consider optimising a tiny bit by defining mask = A == 0 and using mask and ~mask in the calls. And instead of np.where(mask) consider using np. asarray(mask).nonzero() instead, as indicated in the documentation https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

The double where approach seems the fastest. As noted in comment you can slightly improve it by saving the mask.
I also tested other approaches: numba and argsort + split, numba was quite slower and argsort+diff was not better.
Assuming this test array:
np.random.seed(0)
A = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=10_000_000)

Below are the timings for various approaches:
Original approach
zero_indices = np.where(A==0) 
nonzero_indices = np.where(A!=0)
# 137 ms ± 10.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Reusing the mask
mask = A == 0
zero_indices = np.where(mask)
nonzero_indices = np.where(~mask)
# 122 ms ± 959 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

argsort+split
mask = A==0
tmp = np.argsort(mask, kind='stable')
nonzero_indices, nonzero_indices = np.split(tmp, [len(A)-mask.sum()])
# 125 ms ± 17.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

Numba
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def zero_nonzero(A):
    zero_indices = []
    nonzero_indices = []
    for i, item in enumerate(A):
        if item == 0:
            zero_indices.append(i)
        else:
            nonzero_indices.append(i)
    return zero_indices, nonzero_indices

zero_indices, nonzero_indices = zero_nonzero(A)
# 437 ms ± 10.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

setdiff1d
zero_indices = np.where(A == 0)
non_zero_indices = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(A.size), zero_indices)
# 519 ms ± 10.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

timings with A = np.zeros(10_000_000):
# double where + reusing the mask
22 ms ± 113 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# argsort + split
34.5 ms ± 2.66 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)


Thank you for the detailed tests! One thing I'm wondering is, why isn't np.where designed to return both zero_indices and nonzero_indices? In principle, couldn't np.where(A) create both of these outputs with just a single pass through the array A, without sacrificing speed?

That's true, but it would also require a bit more computation and potentially much more memory. I guess this could be an optional flag.
